# Facebook Friend Request - Error - 'All users in param ids must have accepted TOS'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

For a Facebook Challenge Application, I’m trying to send a request to friend, it returns an error message

The error message is:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) All users in param ids must have accepted TOS",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

My request is

https://graph.facebook.com/'user_id'/apprequests?message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&access_token='access_tocken_id'&method=post.

But for another user (ie; user who already accepted our request), it works fine.

How can i solve this?

Thanks,

LS Developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only send app requests to users who already use the app - to send user-user requests you should use the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)